# Issue with Telegram desktop update

Tags: windows-10, updates

I am having a bit of an annoying issue, i.e. my Telegram desktop app is not updating. I click update on the app, and it will not update but continues to give me error msg, "Telegram.exe is not accessible in the file path" which I have checked already and the .exe file is there. Any help?

Comment: Did you register as a user with your phone number when you installed it?

Comment: Yes, it has always updated fine to this point

Comment: Uninstall the app (Control Panel, Programs and Features), restart, and re-install.

Comment: Will this destroy any of my existing data

Comment: I cannot answer that question.

Comment: That worked with no loss of data, praise God!

Comment: @Bryce Steuer, submit that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the App is properly registered, uninstall the app (Control Panel, Programs and Features), restart, and re-install it.

That works for most applications.

Answer (score 1):

Do *not* uninstall the app, as you may lose your login information.

Instead, [download](https://desktop.telegram.org/) the last version of the app, and then in your Telegram installation folder (e.g. "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Telegram Desktop") rename `Telegram.exe` into something else. Then you may run the installer, and the current executive file will not interfere with the new version executive.

In case something goes wrong, you may rename your old .exe to its previous name and still have the old version.